# Looking for a short story: one man is "lucky" enough to live forever through coincidences

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a story online years ago, but I can't find it anymore. The idea behind this story (pretty sure it was a short story, not even a novella) was some kind of many-worlds thing: there are an infinite number of universes, and all manner of coincidences happen somewhere, and *you* never observe the universes in which you happened to die. So, your subjective experience is that through a series of increasingly unlikely coincidences, you somehow manage to stay alive. In the end, the protagonist outlives everyone he knows, and eventually all other life on Earth; I remember the story ending when some aliens discover Earth and start investigating him, but I could be wrong about that bit.

Comment: Well, I don't know the story you are talking about, but what you are describing is quantum immortality; [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_quantum_immortality_in_fiction), or possibly [this one (*Warning -- TVTropes; you can lose hours here*)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SaveScumming) may help you find it.

Comment: @MikeScott Yep, same story, and similar question. I'd vote to close it myself if I had enough rep here; is deleting right? I'd think not, since this question may still be usefully found by google searchers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably one of the stories mentioned in the Wikipedia article on [Quantum suicide and quantum immortality in fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_quantum_immortality_in_fiction). I think the one you're looking for is ["Divided by Infinity"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84491) by Robert Charles Wilson; you can read it [here](http://www.tor.com/stories/2010/08/divided-by-infinity)